# How do I prevent Atom from updating a package?

Tags: updates, plugins, atom-editor

[atom-script](https://atom.io/packages/script) has [a major bug](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/1995) that popped up in the latest update so I've reverted to the previous version. The maintainers haven't fixed it after two months, so I'm starting to think they never will. How do I prevent Atom from bugging me to update the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the repository info in the package.json file, and that seems to have stopped it. This should prevent all updates to the package. I'd prefer to skip just the bugged release, but the previous version works fine so whatever.

1. Go to **Preferences** (or **Settings**) then **Open Config Folder**
2. Open `packages/script/package.json`
3. Comment out the repository info. JSON doesn't support comments, so instead I put it under an unused key:

   Replace this:

   ```
     "repository": {
       "type": "git",
       "url": "git+https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script.git"
     },
   ```

   With something like this:

   ```
     "COMMENTED OUT to avoid updating to 3.25.0": {
       "repository": {
         "type": "git",
         "url": "git+https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script.git"
       }
     },
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are third-party packages such as [`auto-update-plus`](https://atom.io/packages/auto-update-plus) that have support to ignore specific packages from being updated.